# What was/is the origin, direction of flow and countries watered by the Drishadvati River as per scriptures?

Tags: puranas, shatapatha-brahmana, rivers, story

As per [one site](https://www.rajras.in/ancient-rivers-rajasthan-sarasvati-drishadvati/) it is said that the Drishadvati river originates from the pot of Brahma (maybe at Pushkara). Apparently this reference has been taken from the Satapatha Brahmana.

**Question**

1. Would like as much information about what various texts about the origin, direction of flow of the Drishadvati and the kingdoms that it waters. Especially the Satapatha brahmana reference about pushkara and Drishadvati.
2. Is there any Drishadvati Mahatmya? Or any Pushkara mahatmya that describes the Drishadvati river?

---

<sup>**Note:** I don’t think that the mention of Kurukshetra being exactly between Saraswati and Drishadvati and Drishadvati flowing northwards has any correct basis. So please give reference other than this. Also I’m aware of the Manusmriti speaking of Brahmavarta and Matysas etc being in the Drishadvati region. So please don’t repeat that</sup>